# Redirecting to new url with ajax and express routing

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, ejs

I have a button with `id: 'tune-in'` on a page `auth.ejs`, which on click should go to a new page `index.ejs`.

However, when I click the button, the `index` page is not rendered. Instead, I'm still on the `auth` page, however I do have the message "should display tune-in home page" logged to the console.

**On the html (ejs) page (views folder > auth.ejs)**

```
  document.getElementById('tune-in').addEventListener('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/tune-in',
      success: function(){
        console.log("should display tune-in home page");
      }
    });
}, false);
```

**controllers folder > authController.js**

```
  app.get('/tune-in', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
  });
```

**views folder > index.ejs**
This is just a regular html page, should be rendered on click.

EDIT: 
**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// userController takes care of rendering the view and
// routing requests to the server
var authController = require('./controllers/authController');
var userController = require('./controllers/userController');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('./public'))
   .use(cookieParser());

authController(app);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);
console.log("Listening to port 4000...");
```

Comment: Can I you add you `app.js` or whatever the your main file is? Also could you add where you are handling the routing? I want to see if you are setting the templating correct and if you are setting your routes correctly.

Comment: This behavior is really expected as you not asking to render the page. $.ajax just fetch the content of index. It won't render the content until you tell it to.

Comment: @AnamulHasan But I'm telling it to render in authController.js

Comment: you want to render the content of index replacing the content of auth.ejs. am i right?

Comment: @AnamulHasan Yep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong this is what you need.

```
 document.getElementById('tune-in').addEventListener('click', function() {
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/tune-in',
  success: function(data){
    console.log("should display tune-in home page");
    // data must be valid html
    $("html").html(data); // this line tells to load the data
    // $("#otherid").html(data);
   }
 });
}, false);
```

Comment: I think the content you receiving isn't valid html. So it's not loading correctly, instead showing empty page.

Comment: No, I was reloading `auth.ejs` by accident. I'd changed to that from index a few minutes ago. Your answer worked perfectly, thanks!